# Best way to create PDF from XML XSLT in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I have a requirement to crate a PDF of XML Records. I think there is no way to directly create pdf from xml but using XSLT or XSL FO i believe it can be done. I have been reading lots of articles searching for the good way to do that using C#.

--> What's the best approach of during this? any example would really be great.

My Scenario:

I have XML that looks like:

```
<Products>
  <Brand name="Test">
    <Quantity value="2/>
     <Price value="$20"/>
  </Brand>
  <Brand name="Test2">
    <Quantity value="3/>
     <Price value="$30"/>
  </Brand>
  <Brand name="Test3">
    <Quantity value="4/>
     <Price value="$40"/>
  </Brand>
</Products>
```

How can i create a pdf that will have a table showing all this information?

I know there are lots of similar questions like this but most of them are outdated. Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Since you mention FO: have you *tried* FO? For example fonet.codeplex.net ? Note that FO is not trivial - you need to do a lot more work that you would for HTML, as an example. Also: have you considered any of the html-to-PDF conversion tools? (I used to use HTMLDOC a lot, a few years back). Or any of the low-level PDF creation tools?

Comment: duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674257/using-xml-xslt-and-c-sharp-to-create-an-rtf-or-pdf

Comment: As i mentioned they are mostly outdated the last update for FO was on 2009. I am looking for something which can be easily used in C# , and can be taken as best tool for automating the pdf creation through code. I have looked at http://report.sourceforge.net/, http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/index.php, http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/ and few more but need feedbacks from those who have used it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the past I've used a commercial library called [Ibex PDF Creator](http://www.xmlpdf.com) to generate PDF documents from XML data using the XSL-FO standard that has worked really well.

Here's an example of how I would use it:

**XML data:**

```
<DocumentRoot>
    <!-- Some content -->
</DocumentRoot>
```

**XSL-FO layout:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/DocumentRoot">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:ibex="http://www.xmlpdf.com/2003/ibex/Format">
            <ibex:properties
                title="Some document"
                subject=""
                author=""
                keywords=""
                creator="" />
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-bottom="1cm" margin-top="3cm"/>
                    <fo:region-before extent="20mm"/>
                    <fo:region-after extent="8mm"/>
                    <fo:region-start extent="1mm"/>
                    <fo:region-end extent="1mm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
        </<fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Generating the PDF document in .NET:**

```
var data = new MemoryStream(dataBytes);
var layout = new MemoryStream(layoutBytes);
var pdf = new MemoryStream();

// Using the Ibex PDF Creator .NET API
var doc = new FODocument();
doc.generate(data, layout, pdf);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Enrico do you suggest any opensource alternatives?

Comment: Personally, I haven't tried any open source alternative for XSL-FO. Since the project I was working on was about building a product, we chose to go with a commercial library for the documentation and support.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Apache Fop.bat in a method like this. (using System.Diagnostics)

```
    private void XML_TO_PDF_VIA_FOP(String xmlName, String xsltName, String pdfName) 
    { 
      String batchFile = "XSLT\\FOPv1\\fop.bat";    
      String xmlFile = xmlName;
      String xsltFile = "XSLT\\" + xsltName; 
      String pdfFile = pdfName; 
      Process.Start(batchFile, " -xml " + xmlFile + " -xsl " + xsltFile + " -pdf " + pdfFile); 
    }
```

Comment: how to create  Fop.bat ?

Answer (score -1):

You can create pdf file from xml by using Aspose.PDF for .NET API. I could find the code sample for **[transforming xml to pdf in C#/.NET](https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfnet/Create+a+Hello+World+PDF+Document+through+XML+and+XSLT)** on Aspose documentation page for pdf.